# PowerBuilder Classic 12/12.5 guide/tutorials

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm new to PowerBuilder Classic 12, and I'm having a hard time finding any good guide/tutorial that can help me get started.

Now I have already read the following tutorials http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37772.1250/html/pbgs/CHDFGFBFA.htm

But it did not explain how to build a application from scratch. It had a wizard that auto-creates windows, sheets, menu and etc for you.

Any help/guide/tutorials are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

edit: Forgot to mention that I find a lot of PB.NET stuff, which is not what I am looking for. I'm looking for PB Classic learning stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iI had a new collegue to whom I had to provide some learning material. I give them the following and right now he become a PB developer at my side :) I hope this helps for you too:

http://anvil-of-time.com/wordpress/category/powerbuilder/100-days-of-powerbuilder/

http://powerbuilder.hyderabad-colleges.com/powerbuilder.html

- For beginners: start with Introduction to PowerBuilder 7, but you
  should skip the first few lesson because they are obsolete, so you
  can start from here: PowerBuilder Environment
- For advanced developers: Advanced PowerBuilder 7
- For Jedi Masters: Mastering PowerBuilder 7

Getting Started ebooks: download from here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp

Br. Gábor

Answer (score 1):

There's also some basic PowerBuilder information here: http://www.woodger.ca/pb_strt.htm

Answer (score 1):

There is a link to well [over 100 PowerBuilder Training, Tips, and Reference Document links](http://www.displacedguy.com/tech/powerbuilder-12-5-pb-net-free-training-and-tutorials/), most of which are PB12 or 12.5 or newer with reference material for PB versions going back many years. The page is updated many times a year and has been nearly four years in the making. Disclaimer, it is my own PowerBuilder blog.