# PowerBuilder pasting in tabbed data window

Tags: tabs, powerbuilder

I recently started a new job with a company and my first task is to update some quite old software for them.

There is a big back story but basically the software was written in PB8 (around 1997) and no one within the company (including me) has had any experience with PowerBuilder before and as the newbie I have been tasked to update and maintain it until a replacement has been approved and can be developed.

We have the license for PowerBuilder 12.5 so I am using PB12.5 Classic to do everything. The original developer cannot be contacted for support and no documentation exists.

One thing I am trying to understand, that will be a huge help in the future, is how to determine where functions are defined and where variables get their values..

The example I am working on at the moment is the following scenario.
There is a data window with tabs, named `tab_detail` each tab displays different *whatever little orange men are in the tree list*.

One of these are called `dw_detail` which allows pasting of data. None of the other tabs allow pasting of data, but I would like them to. `dw_detail` has an event `rbuttondown()` with the following code in it:

```
    Window  w_parentwin

    If ib_add_mode Or ib_chg_mode Then
        w_parentwin = Parent.GetParent().GetParent()

        m_dwpaste   m_pop_paste
        m_pop_paste = CREATE m_dwpaste

        m_pop_paste.idw_data = This

        If ii_agent_code > 0 And Not IsNull(id_period) And Clipboard() <> "" Then
            m_pop_paste.m_popup.m_paste.Enabled = TRUE
        Else
            m_pop_paste.m_popup.m_paste.Enabled = FALSE
        End If

        m_pop_paste.m_popup.PopMenu(w_parentwin.PointerX(), w_parentwin.PointerY())        

        DESTROY(m_pop_paste)
    End If
```

When I add that code to the `rbuttondown()` event of tab number 2 (`dw_adjustment`) tab 2 now allows paste when I right click within the `dw_adjustment` data window but the data gets pasted to the fields within the `dw_detail` tab not the fields on the `dw_adjustment` tab.

I have tried debugging and stepping through the code but there are thousands of values in the variable window and without the ability to search I cannot find the variables used above and what their values are or why data gets pasted to the `dw_detail` tab instead of the `dw_adjustment` tab when I paste into the `dw_adjustment` tab.

Basically I am looking for any helpful tips on where to look or what the above is doing and why everything pastes to tab 1 instead of the tab I clicked paste in.

If more detail is needed from code from a different location or more information is needed I am happy to provide it.

As suggested by Seki I found the `m_popup` when double clicked it came up with `wf_pastereturn()`:

```
Integer li_idx, li_rows, li_dwrows, li_comm, li_seqno
String  ls_approval_type

If tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.RowCount() > 0 Then
    li_idx = 1
    li_dwrows = tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.RowCount()

    Do Until li_idx > li_dwrows
        ls_approval_type = tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.approval_type [li_idx]
        If IsNull(ls_approval_type) or ls_approval_type = "" Then
            tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.DeleteRow(li_idx)
        Else
            li_idx++
        End If
        li_dwrows = tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.RowCount()
    Loop
End If

If li_dwrows > 0 Then
    li_seqno = Long(tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.seq_no [li_dwrows])
End If
li_seqno += 10


If Clipboard() <> "" Then
    If tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.ImportClipboard(1, li_rows, 1, 4, 3) <= 0 Then
        MessageBox("Invalid Data", "Unable to paste!", StopSign!)
        Return -1
    End If
    li_rows = tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.RowCount()
    li_dwrows++
    For li_idx = li_dwrows To li_rows
        tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.approval_type [li_idx] = trim(tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.approval_type [li_idx])
        tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.approval_no [li_idx] = trim(tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.approval_no [li_idx])
        tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.agent_code [li_idx] = ii_agent_code
        tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.period [li_idx] = id_period
        li_comm = f_new_commission(Long(tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.value_of_work[li_idx]), id_period)
        tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.levy_payable[li_idx]= &
            inv_rate.of_CalculateLevyPayable (Long(tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.value_of_work[li_idx]), id_period)
        tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.comm_deductable [li_idx] = li_comm
        tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.commission [li_idx] = li_comm
        tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.seq_no [li_idx] = li_seqno
        li_seqno += 10
        tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.agent_return_detail_create_date[li_idx] = Today()
        tab_detail.tabpage_details.dw_detail.Object.agent_return_detail_create_user[li_idx] = SQLCA.Logid
    Next
    Clipboard("")
    Return 0
Else
    Return -1
End If
```

I modified the function to use the windows `SelectedTab` property. Data will now paste into the tab but in the wrong input fields. I looked further and the data columns for the `ImportClipboard` function do not line up.

How is the best way to change the order of the selected database columns?

Here is a screenshot of what I mean by tabs:
[image]

So within the main program window, there are the above tabs, within each tab (where the input fields are) there is a data window labelled with the `dw_` prefix.

Thanks heaps for your help.

Comment: One thing complicating giving advice is that you're referring to "tabs" with names prefixed by dw_. Assuming the developer has used popular naming standards promoted by the various makers of PowerBuilder (Powersoft, Sybase, SAP), these are more likely DataWindows than tabs. (The usage of them in the code also suggests DataWindows.) If you have what we PB developers call tabs, and you want behaviour to change based on the selected tab, that is one piece of advice. If these DWs are panes on a single window, that's other advice. Can you confirm?

Comment: updated original post with more info on how the tabs are setup.

Comment: Too bad you lost the developer, his/her code is nice. I love the way he made it like functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you should do some short tutorials. Please check out these:

[PowerBuilder Classic 12/12.5 guide/tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918399/powerbuilder-classic-12-12-5-guide-tutorials/15918999#15918999)

These are short and useful.

On the other side you are able to select specific variables in your own "watch variable" list, so you do not have to search over the several variables. You can right click on the variable name and do a Quickwatch or you can Insert the variable name in the Watch window.

Br. Gábor

Answer (score 0):

The action with a contextual menu is in 2 times :

- handle the mouse right click to display a contextual menu
- perform an action among the one or several actions provided by the popup menu

You shown the pbscript that is displaying the menu with `PopMenu()` if there is something in the clipboard (`Clipboard() <> ""`) and maybe you did not noticed that the pasting action is somewhere else.

Look in `m_popup`: there must be some code inside that may be hard-coded to paste in `dw_detail`. If so, maybe that you could store in the window instance variables a reference to the currently processed dw for the contextual menu.

Something like :

- `datawindow idw_current` in the instance variables
- then in the `rbuttondown()` event `idw_current = this` (this being the datawindow the `rbuttondown()` event belongs to)
- and finally in the menu reuse the `id_current` instead of a hardcoded `dw_detail`

Concerning your question about where the variables are modified: what you can do is searching the variables by their name (right click on the target or a single pbl or object then 'search'), and put a breakpoint on the lines where they are affected. If you run in debug mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) you will be able to trace when a variable is modified.

Answer (score 0):

### Paste Problem

#### Pass 1

It's hard to tell for sure, but I'd look at the code of m_dwpaste.m_popup.m_paste.Clicked. The worse case scenario is that dw_detail is hard coded into that script; the slightly better case is that it has a more flexible routine in there, but somehow dw_adjustment doesn't fit into that algorithm.

#### Pass 2

With the new information, we can see that the code of wf_pastereturn() (I'm not sure how you got to this script, but this looks like the culprit) is not simply pasting, but doing a lot more that involves specific fields. In fact, it's not just pasting, it's *importing* the data, which means that it's assuming the contents of the clipboard are not only in a specific format, but match the data set of the DataWindow (see the Columns pane in the DW painter, and be careful not to confuse the data set part of the DataWindow with the UI part). The question is, do you want:

- "Pasting" like copying text from Notepad into a browser form; just putting text into the current field?
- "Pasting" *exactly* like the other DataWindow, including assumptions that all the same columns mentioned in the script are in both DataWindows?
- "Pasting" *something* like this script, but customized for the data set in the new DataWindow?

These all require somewhat different solutions, combined with the differences I asked about in my comment about tabs vs. DataWindows.

### Finding Stuff

I'm going to give an unapologetically biased point of view, because I'm the author of a tool that, among other things, helps you search PowerBuilder code called [PBL Peeper](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PBL_Peeper/Download/download.html).

If you're looking at code in the Browse tab, and you want to see other mentions of the variable, you can select it, right click, and either

- search forward or back within the script
- search for the object name in the tree on the left (it'll make more sense when you see it)
- search either the rest of the object or the rest of the application

Finding where a variable is assigned is more difficult than it sounds, because of the multiple syntaxes that could be involved.

```
// assigns a value on instantiation
int i = 1

// assigns a value when executed
i = 1

// does not assign a value
IF i = 1 THEN

// assigns a value possibly if the parameter is passed by reference (kind of like a pointer to the variable)
f_foo (i)
```

Finding the setting of a variable can be helped by understanding variable scope. If the variable is local, you only need to search the script. If the scope is instance or shared, you need to search the object (as above, pretty easy) and its descendants (easy to go to a given descendant with an RMB on the treeview, harder to search on a set of descendants). If the scope is global, you want to search the entire app.

Finding where a selected function is declared is possible, but you need to know a little secret (or RTFM). The Find on the RMB menu uses the parameters from the Find page, so you need to set Portion Type to All, not just Scripts, to find where functions are declared. Alternatively, you can use the Lists / Scripts pages and find the script using the functions on that page (Find, QuickFind, Filter, etc...).

The tool has a plethora of functionalities that let you find, filter and sift through code to get at what you're after. The above is just a quick introduction.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Hi Terry, it's pasting as in multiple cells from Excel to match the PB input boxes. Thanks for the tool I will be sure to use it and let you know how I go.