# How to pull distinct date from database from powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

[Code to check already existing date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9B1A.png)

I have to check for the exisitingdate and also insert new row if new date is inserted.

Comment: Check out my answer to the same problem :) [Tutorials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918399/powerbuilder-classic-12-12-5-guide-tutorials/15918999#15918999)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the links below.  The 1st one is free and it is from older version of PB but the concepts still apply.  The 2nd one will cost you some money but it includes the latest techniques.

http://powerbuilder.hyderabad-colleges.com/powerbuilder.html

http://elearnitonline.com/training/